# AWS: Saving every SNS message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

What's the easiest way to save/log every message published on a AWS SNS topic? I thought there might be a magic setting to automatically push them to S3 or a database, or maybe a database service supporting the HTTP destination automatically, but doesn't seem to be the case. Maybe it needs to be done via a Lambda function?

The purpose is just for basic diagnostics and debugging while setting up some SNS publishing. I don't really care about high scale or fast querying, just want to log and perform basic queries on all the activity for a few minutes at a time.

Comment: Can't this be done by the application that is processing the message?

Comment: It could be, but I'm trying to avoid developing a custom UI within AWS. Looking for a generic + basic querying interface.

Comment: Tried this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html.

Comment: you can select an application and select "delivery status" and then "create iam roles" and then "save configuration", this will log to cloudwatch every successful and failed delivery.

Comment: Cloudwatch might be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a trigger to push your `SNS` messages to `SQS` queue. Push is automatic and does not require any code.

Comment: Is SQS able to be used for querying purposes? Given that it's designed for short-lived messages, I would have thought it has very limited querying capability and expensive storage.

Comment: yes. you can query SQS messages. Up to 10 per `receive` call. https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/. `limited querying capability and expensive storage` is subjective.

Comment: @mahemoff you can't actually *query* SQS messages, if by querying you mean selectively searching through them.  You can preview a few at a time in the console, or consume from the queue and save them elsewhere... but SQS stores them at no charge until read and deleted or they die of old age, whichever comes first... default 4 days, configurable up to 14, with no storage charge, and the number of messages in a queue at any one time is unlimited.  It's a very effective way to capture messages from SNS for debugging.  I use a script that can scrape them off the queue and stash in a DB or file.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It's not ideal then. I'm trying to avoid writing t(and deploying) that script and seeing what options are available to get the data into a queryable form purely by configuration.

Comment: @mahemoff wire a Lambda function to the SNS topic and have the function send each message to CloudWatch logs.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html), SNS can publish to:

```
http – delivery of JSON-encoded message via HTTP POST
https – delivery of JSON-encoded message via HTTPS POST
email – delivery of message via SMTP
email-json – delivery of JSON-encoded message via SMTP
sms – delivery of message via SMS
sqs – delivery of JSON-encoded message to an Amazon SQS queue
application – delivery of JSON-encoded message to an EndpointArn for a mobile app and device.
lambda – delivery of JSON-encoded message to an AWS Lambda function.
```

So yes, a simple approach would be to trigger a lambda function to write to S3 or CloudWatch.