# How can I view the sms text sent using AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

Is there any way in AWS SNS to check what SMS text was sent through a particular region using messageId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS doesn't log the body content of the messages that are sent.

If you want to see the body content of the SMS messages you could add logging in whatever code/process is invoking the SNS send action or otherwise add some code to store that detail.  But otherwise, you won't be able to get the SMS message body details through a built-in AWS feature.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528272/aws-saving-every-sns-message) has some info on storing every message.

[Logging and Monitoring in Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-logging-monitoring.html) has info on what gets logged for *some* API calls, but notice that it does not log the `Publish` action to CloudTrail--just other actions that are related to the setup of SNS.  And CloudWatch logs give metrics about the process, but not individual message content.